# scrapy extract source url from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying extract data from javascript. js looks like -

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("player");
playerInstance.setup({
    image: "http://cdn1.gomoviesgo.com/movies/1230451279-cover-Wonder-Woman.jpg",
    sources: JSON.parse('[{"file":"http:\/\/stream.gomo.to\/home\/movies\/tt0451279.mp4","label":"720<sup>HD<\/sup>"}]'),
    width: "100%"
});
</script>
```

I need image url which is `http://cdn1.gomoviesgo.com/movies/1230451279-cover-Wonder-Woman.jpg` and source url which is `"http:\/\/stream.gomo.to\/home\/movies\/tt0451279.mp4"`

Please guide.

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: how I can get these data. unable to implement code.

Comment: Is your scrapper in python? Are you treating the 'javascript.js' as a plain text file in your scrapper?

Comment: yes ia am using python. I am getting this script in response.body

Comment: So do you want to [`document.createElement("img")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) set its `src` and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild`) somewhere?

Comment: I need these two urls from this script- http://cdn1.gomoviesgo.com/movies/1230451279-cover-Wonder-Woman.jpg ,  "http:\/\/stream.gomo.to\/home\/movies\/tt0451279.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse js with html parsers, but you can use regular expressions.

```
image = re.search('image:\s*"(.*?)",', data).group(1)
file = re.search('"file":"(.*?)",', data).group(1).replace('\\', '')
```

Or you could use the built-in [`re`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.re) method.

```
image = response.css('script::text').re('image:\s*"(.*?)",')[0]
file = response.css('script::text').re('"file":"(.*?)",')[0].replace('\\', '')
```